# Cannot get a margin between cards in Recycler

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have the following content for my recycler card element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardview_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="6dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_category_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_own_groceries" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_item_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button_plus"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageview_category_icon"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Item Name"
            android:textColor="@color/grayDark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_plus"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button_minus"
            android:background="@color/greenDark"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_minus"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button_status"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/redDark"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_status"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button_edit"
            android:background="@color/grayMedium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_edit"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick="goToEditor"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Unfortunately, `android:layout_marginTop="4dp"` in the root element does **not** seem to have an effect on the margin between consecutive cards in the app display. In fact, there is no margin at all, no matter to what value I change the "4dp". On the other hand, `android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"` works fine.

Also, `app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"` has no effect either, though when visualizing in Android Studio only this layout file, the rounded corners do appear.

As suggested by answers to a similar question, I did use `"wrap_content"` for `height` wherever possible. To no avail.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted by the author of the question.

The problem persists, but I found a hack by inserting above `RelativeLayout` an empty `TextView` with the same height as the desired top margin.